# how can i Delete a file from the server using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My web host gave me a very low space. I want to delete the image files from an entry listed on mysql database row whenever its deleted.The database structure has a post title, a category id, post id and five images directory details I use an older version of XAMPP on my windows 10 PC so that i can use both mysql and msqli queries. :) Sorry for my English . I was in a bit of haste.thank you.

Comment: [unllink](http://php.net/unlink)?

Answer (score 0):

In php there is the [unlink()-function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) to delete files. So you have to fetch the filedata from the database, delete the file and then delete the row.

Answer (score 0):

the function you are looking for is [unlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

now regarding the space issue.you need to scan the files then match them with database,then remove the unnecessary ones.

Scan your filenames like this:

```
$filenames = [];
foreach (glob(__DIR__."/Models/*") as $filename){
array_push($filenames, $filename);
}
```

you can now see if the files are needed by retrieving filenames from your database. I'm on mobile, couldn't give the full code but this should solve your problems.